# Single iptable rule matching /32 and jump

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking

We need to install a single iptables rule that match every source /32 user ip and jump to 'user chain':

```
iptables -A INPUT -s "EVERY_USER-IP/32" -j "USER_IP/32_CHAIN"
```

because we have hundreds of users we need/prefer to avoid using a lot of user-ip/32 rules like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s "USER-IP1/32" -j "USER_IP1/32_CHAIN"

iptables -A INPUT -s "USER-IP2/32" -j "USER_IP2/32_CHAIN"
```

...

Comment: So what are you asking for help with? Either you want a separate chain for each IP or you don't. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Newer nftables with [verdict maps](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Dictionaries) could probably help there (more than [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/features.html) ).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a different set of firewall rules per user-ip, you need to create a chain for every user-ip. Then, you need to fill each chain with the correct rules.

We can not suggest a better way unless you tell us about your ruleset and whether it is really necessary to have a complete different set of rules per user-ip.

If you are worried about iptables capability to handle large ruleset, I have a working firewall with +60,000 rules.

Comment: Yes, we're worried about iptables capability to handle large ruleset. What's the max bandwidth you reached with 60000 rules ? What can you tell me about firewall CPU and memory usage ? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The first half of your question sounds like the perfect use case for [`ipset`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html)

You manage the collection of ip-addresses with `ipset` and in your iptables rule-sets you refer to that collection, rather than the individual ip-addresses. That makes your rule-base a lot smaller and will perform much better.

```
ipset create our-users hash:net hashsize 4096
```

Add ip-addresses to that new collection:

```
ipset add our-users 192.168.0.5 
ipset add our-users 192.168.0.100
```

And then when the source ip-address is present in that collection do something useful:

```
iptables -I INPUT  -m set --match-set our-users src -j ALLOW
```

But the second part of your current question seems to imply that for every know source IP-address you have (some) custom rules in a unique chain. If that is really the case, then you will indeed end up with a lot of rules.